# The connection between Tzitzis and teeth

Tags: tzitzis, health-safety-shmira, teeth

Rabbi Moishe Dovid Lebovits, author of the Halachically Speaking series, is coming out with a book on Teeth and Dentistry in Halacha. In the [flyer advertising the book](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/teethflyer.pdf) (PDF), there is a list of the topics covered in the book. One of these topics is "Tzitzis and Teeth".

What is the connection between Tzitzis and teeth?

Comment: Cutting tzizts with teeth? Or connection to 32 teeth and 32 strings

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic because the answer is given in the book -- why guess when the answer is provided in the sefer?

Comment: Maybe the suspense is too much...

Comment: After I had my wisdom teeth removed, one of the rebbeim at my yeshiva facetiously accused me of being אחד בפה ואחד בלב (now that I no longer had 32 teeth).

Comment: This sound like a riddle, not a real question.

Comment: @rosends the sefer isn't out yet..

Comment: @Menachem _davar sheyesh lo matirin_

Comment: @msh210 I don't have the sefer :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wearing Tzitzit helps reduce toothaches and teeth pains

This is brought in a [Hirhurim blogpost on Tzitzit](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2008/02/tying-tzitzit-at-night-more.html):

> It is said that being careful in the observance of the mitzva of Tzitzit is a segula for preventing tooth aches. [Kaf Hachaim 11:17].

The Kaf Hachaim (Sofer), brings it [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14418&pgnum=55). He, in turn, is quoting the Kaf Hachaim (Palaggi) 10:12 and others, who quote the Derech Yeshara saying that wearing tzitzit is a segula for preventing toothaches. You can see the Kaf Hachaim (Palaggi) [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53455&pgnum=127). They connect it to the fact that there are 32 teeth in the mouth, and 32 stings on a Tzitzit strings on a garment.

Answer (score 6):

Probably this, from [Magen Avraham 11:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.11.18?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> כ' בשל"ה ומט"מ שאל יחתוך בסכין אלא ינשכם בשיניו ע"ש:
>
> Shaloh and Mateh Moshe say that you shouldn't cut [the tzitzis strings] with a knife, but bite them with your teeth; see there.